# Git Diff: Only highlight character changes, not line changes

Tags: git

I'm using this: `git diff --color-words` on a very long minified line (there's a specific reason it's in version control that's not important for this question).

I'm trying to only show changed words so it's easier to see what's changed, but it is highlighting things that aren't changing:

```
# red
0===n.onload&&(n.onload=!0),n.onload&&!t?o.push(n):i(n)}a=o};n.abo={version:40},n.actions={push:function(o){a.push(o),e()}},n.onload=function(){t=!0,e()},"function"==typeof
# green
0===n.onload&&(n.onload=!0),n.onload&&!t?o.push(n):i(n)}a=o};n.abo={version:41},n.actions={push:function(o){a.push(o),e()}},n.onload=function(){t=!0,e()},"function"==typeof
```

Notice the version number is the only thing that changed.

**Edit: I actually see it's going off of spaces. Is there a way I can change it to be each letter not groups separated by spaces?**

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---word-diffltmodegt

Comment: Can you check my edit @phd?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---word-diff-regexltregexgt

Comment: `git diff -w --color-words`?

Comment: That's highlighting too much, but I see I need to use regex version per what PHD said, i'm working on the command currently. I wonder if I can make each part go on a new line, but I'll get to that later

Comment: You might also consider add-ons like [diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy#with-git).